# Android: post-processing drawn Views

Tags: android, android-layout, render

I have a custom `ViewGroup` (as a root view) with some other Views and I want to put a visual effect on a part of it, affecting its children.

Root view has no background so `draw` and `onDraw` never got called on it.

As noted by **pskink**, I can do it in my custom ViewGroup's `dispatchDraw`. When I, just for test, draw a circle on a `Canvas`, obtained by `dispatchDraw`, it appears. But I cannot get access to the Canvas contents, even `private Bitmap mBitmap` is `null`.

- How can I get (and modify) pixels?
- How system draws on a `Canvas` with no `Bitmap`?

Comment: see `ViewGroup#dispatchDraw` method

Answer (score 1):

1. root RelativeLayout mixes the overlay and list
2. Just override the root RelativeLayout draw method, and create your
   Bitmap, then create a Canvas object with it, the invoke the super
   draw method with you canvas object, and you will get your overlay
   and list  drawn content from the bitmap, then you can draw it by
   your self
3. From the native code, pass through from ViewRootImpl to all Views in view tree, if your hardware accuserate turn on, the canvas object is instance of GLES20RecordingCanvas

Comment: Tang, thank you for your feedback.
1. Of course. But, most likely, it does it in dispatchDraw method, as noted by **pskink**.
2. *root*'s `draw` and `onDraw` both never called.
3. You mean that I need to use NDK?